# float:left hover effect. i want it to be centered but because of the float:left it stays left

Tags: css, hover

How do i get my links to to stay center. i want it above my container in center. it keeps going left. if i change the float it stops the jump effect. i tried putting a margin in but that does nothing. please help i want the jump hover effect but i dont want it right or left but in the center. Does anyone know another way of making my links jump on hover other than the code i have below.

```
         A.main:link, A.main:active, A.main:visited{
         font-family: arial narrow; 
         color: #404040; 
         font-size: 20px; 
         text-align: center; 
         letter-spacing: 5px; 
         text-transform: lowercase; 
         font-weight: normal;
         border:double;
         float: left;
         margin: 15px;
         -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
         -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
         -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
          }


      A.main:hover {
         margin-top: 2px;
         }


           #container {
             margin: 0px auto;
           padding-left:15px;
           width: 800px;
           height: auto;
           background: #000;
           border-style:double;
           box-shadow: 15px 15px 5px #333;
          -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #333;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #333;}

         </head> 
         <body>

           <div id="header">
         </div>
          <center>
            <a href="file:///C|/Users/JESS/Desktop/URL" class="main">LINK</a>
            <a href="file:///C|/Users/JESS/Desktop/URL" class="main">LINK</a>
            <a href="file:///C|/Users/JESS/Desktop/URL" class="main">LINK</a>
            <a href="file:///C|/Users/JESS/Desktop/URL" class="main">LINK</a>
            <a href="file:///C|/Users/JESS/Desktop/URL" class="main">LINK</a>
            <a href="file:///C|/Users/JESS/Desktop/URL" class="main">LINK</a>
            </center>

            <div id="container">

            </div>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML as well. ([SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct/Compilable, Example)](http://sscce.org/)). If you could post a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) it'd help, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try manipulating the padding instead of the margin.

```
      A.main:link, A.main:active, A.main:visited{
...
         margin: 0 15px 15px;
         paddding-top:15px;
...
}
     A.main:hover {
         padding-top: 2px;
         }
```

If that doesn't work, you can rewrite the code as follows:

Ditch the "center" element.  Replace it with a div.  Set this div's style to "position:relative".  Specify the style to be "text-align:center" if you want.

Replace each link with a span element.  Specify the onclick for each span ="document.location=the url where you want to go".  In the CSS for each of these spans, use absolute positioning.  Then you can position them wherever you like (using left,right,top, and/or bottom in the style) .

Answer (score 0):

Add a unorered list and li items to the menu. Then add text-align:center to ul and display: inline or inline-block to li. Here is a fiddle about it. http://jsfiddle.net/XhmGe/

Comment: thanks but that doesnt help with my hover jump effect. i need it to be horizontal and have a jump effect when hover.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a code to make it all work out. this centers my tabs :)

```
          #centeredmenu {
             float:left;
             width:100%;
             background:#fff;
             overflow:hidden;
             position:relative;
                    }
          #centeredmenu ul {
             clear:left;
             float:left;
             list-style:none;
             margin:0;
             padding:0;
              position:relative;
             left:50%;
             text-align:center;
                 }
               #centeredmenu ul li {
                 display:block;
                 float:left;
                 list-style:none;
                 margin:0;
                 padding:0;
                 position:relative;
                 right:50%;
                         }
                #centeredmenu ul li a {
                  display:block;
                   margin:0 0 0 1px;
                  padding:3px 10px;
                  background:#ddd;
                  color:#000;
                  text-decoration:none;
                   line-height:1.3em;
                       }
                 #centeredmenu ul li a:hover {
                    background:#369;
                     color:#fff;
                         }
                #centeredmenu ul li a.active,
                #centeredmenu ul li a.active:hover {
                     color:#fff;
                      background:#000;
                      font-weight:bold;
                             }
```